# Using a custom font with the QGIS Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mac, font

I have an issue with changing the font of a text zone in the QGIS composer.

I have downloaded Roboto font and want to use it in my composer instead of Arial black. After installation I quitted QGIS and relaunched it. The font is available in the font list yet when I apply it, it doesn't seems to be changing.

I'm running with QGIS 2.18.20 on a MacBook Pro Machine.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 5):

QGIS uses the fonts that are installed on your computer. When you have downloaded the font, right-click the .otf file and select 'install'. When you close and open QGIS again, the font should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Building off @Laurens answer, on Mac, download the ttf or otf file. Put it in the folder /Library/fonts

[image]

Once you restart QGIS, you'll see the fonts in there. It seems like fontsquirrel tends to have these font downloads.